# How do I deal with C# decimals when using IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, decimal, ironpython

I'm new to IronPython and Python in general.  I'm trying to work with C# decimals and IronPython math functions.  When I try to return the absolute value of an argument, I get a type exception when the argument is a decimal.  Here's my code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CallDecimal()
    {
        var pySrc =
@"def MyAbs(arg):
    return abs(arg)";

        // host python and execute script
        var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.Execute(pySrc, scope);

        // get function with a strongly typed signature
        var myAbs = scope.GetVariable<Func<decimal, decimal>>("MyAbs");

        Assert.AreEqual(5m, myAbs(-5m));
    }
```

The error message I get says:

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.TypeErrorException: bad operand type for abs(): 'Decimal'
```

Is there a Python absolute value function that accepts decimals?  If not, is it easy to write one?  If I could specify the types of function parameters, I'd try to create my own abs function like this:

```
define abs(Decimal arg):
    return arg < 0 ? -arg : arg
```

Comment: You could write a simple function similar to the example you have given.  `def my_abs(arg):  return arg if arg > 0 else -arg`

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard  that worked! Thanks.  Just curious, is there a way to call the built-in abs with a decimal?  Or is there some decimal math library that works with C# decimals?  `abs` is easy to implement, but `atan` isn't

Comment: You may want to look into [dmath](https://code.google.com/p/dmath/).  It provides the atan function for decimals, along with many other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have the option to import the .NET `Math` class and use the methods there.

```
var pySrc =
@"def MyAbs(arg):
    from System import Math
    return Math.Abs(arg)";
```